# Where is break; in Drupal API code?

Tags: hooks

Just found out that on Drupal API hook_help() don't have break after in the end of switch statements. Is it supposed to be so?

```
function hook_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    // Main module help for the block module
    case 'admin/help#block':
      return '<p>' . t('Blocks are boxes of content rendered into an area, or region, of a web page. The default theme Bartik, for example, implements the regions "Sidebar first", "Sidebar second", "Featured", "Content", "Header", "Footer", etc., and a block may appear in any one of these areas. The <a href="@blocks">blocks administration page</a> provides a drag-and-drop interface for assigning a block to a region, and for controlling the order of blocks within regions.', array('@blocks' => url('admin/structure/block'))) . '</p>';

      // Help for another path in the block module
    case 'admin/structure/block':
      return '<p>' . t('This page provides a drag-and-drop interface for assigning a block to a region, and for controlling the order of blocks within regions. Since not all themes implement the same regions, or display regions in the same way, blocks are positioned on a per-theme basis. Remember that your changes will not be saved until you click the <em>Save blocks</em> button at the bottom of the page.') . '</p>';
  }
}
```

Comment: the `return`s do that for you...

Comment: `break` isn't required in a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement... _"If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case."_ That + what @Jimajamma said explains what's going on in your example

Comment: Some folk put a `break` after the `return` to be extra clear, and in case the code's later altered and the `return` gets removed, but as it stands in your example it's entirely unnecessary.

Comment: It's totally obvious. Don't know how I could miss that. @Jimajamma, Clive, Andy Thanks!